# Select DISTINCT IDs with SUM Function in SQL

Tags: sql

I need help with this because I Can't think of a way to do it.

I have this Table:

Score Table:

```
UserID:       1      1    2    1    2    3
Score:       100    -10  100  -10  -20  100
```

So what I need to do is create a view using a SUM function to get the current score of each user, something like this...

View:

```
UserID:     1     2   3
Score:      80   80   100
```

Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Thx for the help, but I'm having another issue.

Now I have another Column in my table (rID) for instance.

```
User ID :      1    2     1    1     2     2

rID:          NULL Null   1    2     1     4

Score:        100  100   -20  -30  -20   -40
```

I want to group by UserID and rID taking diffrents scores for each one of the rID, I want this result:

```
UserID:     1     1     2      2

rID:        1     2     1      4

Score:      80    70    80     60
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Score)
FROM Table
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: @Ramon If you feel like posted answer is correct then upvote the answer, like i did.